# SendGrid with dynamic PHP params

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, sendgrid

Hi All I am trying to do is get a simple PHP contact form on my site to work. I am using bootstrap 3 and SendGrid. I can get it to send an email but I can not seem to get it to pass the contact form params to SendGrid to then send to me.

This is what I have. I just don't understand why something so simple is so complicated.

```
    <?php

$url = 'https://api.sendgrid.com/';
$user = 'XXXXXXXX';
$pass = 'XXXXXXXX';
$first_name = $_POST["firstname"];
$last_name = $_POST["lastname"];
$email = $_POST["email"];
$phone = $_POST["phone number"];
$location = $_POST["locations"];
$bio = $_POST["bio"];


$params = array(
    'api_user'  => $user,
    'api_key'   => $pass,
    'to'        => 'myemail@gmail.com',
    'subject'   => 'I Want To Be A Scout',
    'html'      => $first_name,
    'text'      => '%first_name%',
    'from'      => $email,
  );


$request =  $url.'api/mail.send.json';

// Generate curl request
$session = curl_init($request);
// Tell curl to use HTTP POST
curl_setopt ($session, CURLOPT_POST, true);
// Tell curl that this is the body of the POST
curl_setopt ($session, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $params);
// Tell curl not to return headers, but do return the response
curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

// obtain response
$response = curl_exec($session);
curl_close($session);

// print everything out
print_r($response);

?>
```

By the way if I pass $email in the body of the email it comes through fine, but not any of my other params.

Help! Thanks.

Comment: What does the body of the email look like when you run it like this?

Comment: What happens when you `print_r($_POST)`?

Comment: By the way, @looloobs you should change your SendGrid password. You pasted it into your question.  It's still in the revision history of this question.

Comment: @joeshmo thank you so much! how careless of me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've got these variables `$first_name`, `$last_name`, `$email`, `$phone`, `$location`, `$bio`.  They presumably contain the values submitted by the user.  But you're not giving them (except `$first_name`) to SendGrid.

You probably want to render those variables into a string and pass that as your email body, something like this:

```
$message = "Hey looloobs, somebody named $first_name $last_name from $location "
         . "filled out the form on the website, you can reach them at $phone "
         . "\n\n $bio";
```

Then pass `$message` to SendGrid like this:

```
...
'subject'   => 'I Want To Be A Scout',
'html'      => $message,
'text'      => $message,
'from'      => $email,
...
```

Comment: I thought I did this earlier but clearly not the right thing. Thanks so much works great!