# curlopt_postfields $params 'to' as an array?

Tags: php, arrays, curl

Exact same approach as here: [SendGrid with dynamic PHP params](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25388281/sendgrid-with-dynamic-php-params) but what I'm trying to do is set multiple 'to' and 'cc' email addresses. Can these be set as an array with my current implementation?

```
$params = array(
    'api_user'  => $user,
    'api_key'   => $pass,
    'to' => array('user1@example.com','user2@example.com'),
    'cc' => array('user3@example.com','user4@example.com'),
    'subject'   => 'test email',
    'html'      => '<p>This is a test email</p>',
    'text'      => 'done',
    'from'      => 'admin@example.com'
  );

curl_setopt ($session, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $params;
```

It works well and sends out the email when I only set a single email in the 'to' and 'cc' without an array, but when I add as an array it won't run.

I also tried this but it doesn't run.

```
curl_setopt ($session, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($params);
```

Unfortunately nothing in the documentation explains how to pass in multiple addresses in the to/cc fields - https://sendgrid.com/docs/Code_Examples/php.html.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP's cURL library only knows how to deal with one-dimensional arrays, so you need to build the data string manually using [`http_build_query()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-query.php) and then set that for `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS`.

If you need greater control over the formatting of the data string [eg: file uploads in a complex post] one of the below should work.

```
$params = array(
    'api_user'  => 'foo',
    'api_key'   => 'bar',
    'to' => array('user1@example.com','user2@example.com'),
    'cc' => array('user3@example.com','user4@example.com'),
    'subject'   => 'test email',
    'html'      => '<p>This is a test email</p>',
    'text'      => 'done',
    'from'      => 'admin@example.com',
    'file'      => '@foobar.txt'
);

// returns a query string
function encode1($params) {
        $data_arr = array();
        foreach( $params as $key => $value ){
                if( ! is_array($value) ) {
                        if( strpos($value, '@') === 0 ) { $encvalue = $value; }
                        else { $encvalue = urlencode($value); }
                        $data_arr[] = sprintf('%s=%s', urlencode($key), $encvalue);
                } else {
                        foreach( $value as $item ) {
                                if( strpos($item, '@') === 0 ) { $encvalue = $item; }
                                else { $encvalue = urlencode($item); }
                                $data_arr[] = sprintf('%s=%s', urlencode($key.'[]'), $encvalue);
                        }
                }
        }
        return implode('&', $data_arr);
}
var_dump(encode1($params));
/* result:
string(254) "api_user=foo&api_key=bar&to%5B%5D=user1%40example.com&to%5B%5D=user2%40example.com&cc%5B%5D=user3%40example.com&cc%5B%5D=user4%40example.com&subject=test+email&html=%3Cp%3EThis+is+a+test+email%3C%2Fp%3E&text=done&from=admin%40example.com&file=@foobar.txt"
*/

// returns an array
function encode2($params) {
        $out = array();
        foreach( $params as $key => $value ) {
                if( ! is_array($value) ) {
                        $out[$key] = $value;
                } else {
                        for( $i=0; $i<count($value); $i++ ) {
                                $index = sprintf('%s[%d]', $key, $i);
                                $out[$index] = $value[$i];
                        }
                }
        }
        return $out;
}
var_dump(encode2($params));
/* result:
array(11) {
  ["api_user"]=>string(3) "foo"
  ["api_key"]=> string(3) "bar"
  ["to[0]"]=>   string(17) "user1@example.com"
  ["to[1]"]=>   string(17) "user2@example.com"
  ["cc[0]"]=>   string(17) "user3@example.com"
  ["cc[1]"]=>   string(17) "user4@example.com"
  ["subject"]=> string(10) "test email"
  ["html"]=>    string(27) "<p>This is a test email</p>"
  ["text"]=>    string(4) "done"
  ["from"]=>    string(17) "admin@example.com"
  ["file"]=>    string(11) "@foobar.txt"
}
*/
```

Comment: thank you! Works great! Except now the file data (the csv) contains `'@'.$filePath.'/files/'.$fileName.'.csv'` as the data inside rather than the DB data which it should have.

Comment: how can I specify to not encode the file? `$fileName = $file;
$filePath = dirname(__FILE__); 'files['.$file.'.csv]' => '@'.$filePath.'/files/'.$fileName.'.csv'`

Comment: Well, then you can't use `http_build_query()` and you'll need to modify the code above to skip `urlencode()` for data values that begin with `@`. However, I don't know if the cURL extension will swap in the file contents if the `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS` argument is a string instead of an array. I've modified the function from my original answer, and added a second one that simply flattens the input array.

Comment: Yeah it won't pass in if POSTFIELDS is a string. Thank you for the updated answer, I'll give it a run in the hour and let you know how it went. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

You have to pass the emails as array values. Try the below snippet:

```
$params = array(
    'api_user'  => $user,
    'api_key'   => $pass,
    'to[0]' => 'user1@example.com',
    'to[1]' => 'user2@example.com',
    'cc[0]' => 'user3@example.com',
    'cc[1]' => 'user4@example.com',
    'subject'   => 'test email',
    'html'      => '<p>This is a test email</p>',
    'text'      => 'done',
    'from'      => 'admin@example.com'
);

curl_setopt ($session, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $params;
```

It should work now! :)