# Setting multiple email address for CC param with SendGrid (PHP)

Tags: php, json, email, curl, sendgrid

I am trying to add CC to an email for multiple persons. I see in the [documentation](https://sendgrid.com/docs/API_Reference/Web_API/mail.html), that if i create an array with email address, the cc will the attached but this is unsuccessful.

This is what I have to send CC emails

```
$cc = array('email3@123.net', 'email4@123.net');
$params = array(
        'api_user'  => $user,
        'api_key'   => $password,

        'to'        => "email@123.net",                     
        'toname'    => 'To Name',
        'bcc'       => 'email2@123.net',
        'subject'   => $subject,
        'html'      => $content,
        'from'      => $from,
        'fromname'  => $fromname,
    );

    if(!empty($cc)){
        $params['cc'] =  json_encode($cc);
    }
    $url = $sendGrilUrl; 
    $request =  $url.'api/mail.send.json';
    $session = curl_init($request);
    curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $params);
    curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
    curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    $response = curl_exec($session);
    curl_close($session);           
    $response = json_decode($response);
```

When I do this method, I receive an error from SendGrid stating 'Invalid email address'.

I have tried the method provided at this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27307034/curlopt-postfields-params-to-as-an-array) . The email gets sent but it prints the string as is and is not attractive.

Would really appreciate some assistance, if more details are needed let me know.

Comment: What do you mean *it prints the string as is*?

Comment: When the email array is converted to json with the second link i provided (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27307034/curlopt-postfields-params-to-as-an-array), the email sends but the cc field appears as '0=email3%40123.net&1=email4%40123.net'

Answer (score 3):

You have to pass the emails as array values like cc[0], cc[1] etc.. Try the below snippet:

```
 $params = array(
    'api_user'  => $user,
    'api_key'   => $password,
    'to'        => "email@123.net",                     
    'toname'    => 'To Name',
    'bcc'       => 'email2@123.net',
    'cc[0]'     => 'email3@123.net',
    'cc[1]'     => 'email4@123.net',
    'subject'   => $subject,
    'html'      => $content,
    'from'      => $from,
    'fromname'  => $fromname,
);


$url = $sendGrilUrl; 
$request =  $url.'api/mail.send.json';
$session = curl_init($request);
curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $params);
curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$response = curl_exec($session);
curl_close($session);           
$response = json_decode($response);
```

This should work now! :)